# GridView Редактирование даты, ошибка Incorrect syntax near 'DateOfIssue'. Обработка удаления

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Я через обозреватель серверов подключил `SqlDataSource` одну из таблиц из базы данных. Далее я сделал:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Contract" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyBase %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Contracts]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Contracts SET CustomerID=@CustomerID  DateOfIssue= @DateOfIssue DateOfExecution=@DateOfExecution FROM Contracts Where ContractID=@ContractID"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE From [Contracts] where ContractID=@ContractID" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
<p>Тут буде таблица контрактов Contracts</p>
<asp:GridView HorizontalAlign="Center" ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Contract" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="ContractID" Height="125px" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractID" HeaderText="ContractID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ContractID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfIssue" HeaderText="DateOfIssue" SortExpression="DateOfIssue" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfExecution" HeaderText="DateOfExecution" SortExpression="DateOfExecution" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

В итоге получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при нажатие `правка`  и далее `обновить` получаю ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как правильно редактировать даты? И как обработать удаление, если я это делают через `DeleteCommand`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не хватает запятых. И выражение можно чуть упросить:

```
UPDATE Contracts SET CustomerID=@CustomerID, DateOfIssue= @DateOfIssue, DateOfExecution=@DateOfExecution Where ContractID=@ContractID
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)!!!! Писал, хотел добавить и забыл про них окончательно!!!

Comment: А как обрабатывать исключения? Допустим пытаюсь удалить элемент, а он связан foreign key с другим и не удалить, получу ошибку.

Comment: @Valera задайте отдельным вопросом. но, насколько я помню, с обработкой исключений в webforms все плохо - максимум, можно свою страницу показать вместо стандартной. а лезть в реализацию кастомных datasource не стоит - там все криво, это дикий legacy, не пригодится вам потом нигде - проще уже все сразу на mvc переписать

Comment: спасибо большое